# How can I get IRC Colloquy to catch up history of a channel when I reconnect?

Tags: history, chat, macos

How can I get colloquy to catch up history of a channel when I turn back on my laptop?

I assume its something like leave a bot in the room.

Thanks, Martin.

PS. Perhaps someone would make the tags irc and colloquy for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend just said:

> I'm on a Mac but I shell into a remote server and run irssi in screen, most
>   people I know do that.  The second most common, and what I think you
>   are looking for is: http://wiki.znc.in/ZNC

Comment: Can you explain what the link says - an answer here should be stand alone and links only give extra information